# Index page can't find Alias (AngularJS and Flask)

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, flask, apache2

I'm developing project with `AngulaJS` , `Flask` , `Apache2`.
My index page can't find `css styles`,`js`scripts ,`images` and other sources.
That is from my head tag in HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="/js/app.js"></script>
<script src="/js/services.js"></script>
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
<script src="/js/controllers.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/custom.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js"></script>
```

What's going on? I'm noobie in development. So don't be mad. 
Thanks for you attention!

Comment: What url are You using? `/` in front of assets source (`/js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js`) point to top level domain, so if Your url is something like `http://localhost/myapp/` it won't work

Comment: My URL http://127.0.0.1:5000/index . HTML page and
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js" 
      type="text/javascript"></script>
Are working..
But my own styles and scripts page can't see.

Comment: You should post Your directory structure of project

Comment: Thanks for answering problem solved